# CakePhp Auth Login Issue

Tags: php, cakephp

I am currently setting up a simple authentication on a website using CakePhp, where a user can access any page, but there is an admin system that requires being logged into.

The authorization is working fine, only the admin pages are being restricted and are being redirected to the login page. The issue that I'm having is that I cannot log in as an admin. I have one admin record inserted into the database, with a password that has been hashed. But when I attempt to login it doesn't drop into the `if($this->Auth->login())` as it should be doing. Here is the code I am using:

**App Controller:**

```
class AppController extends Controller {

    public $components = array(
       'Session',
       'Auth' => array(
           'loginRedirect' => array('controller' => 'admins', 'action' => 'index'),
           'logoutRedirect' => array('controller' => 'admins', 'action' => 'index'),
       )
   );

   function beforeFilter() {

        if ($this->params['controller'] != 'admins') {
          $this->Auth->allow('*');
        }
        $this->Auth->loginAction = array('controller' => 'admins', 'action' => 'login');
  }

}
```

**AdminsController:**

```
class AdminsController extends AppController {
var $components = array('Auth');

public function beforeFilter() {
    parent::beforeFilter();
    $this->Auth->allow('login');//allow the login page to be accessed.
}

public function login() {
    if($this->request->is('post')) {

            if($this->Auth->login())
            {
                return $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'admins', 'action' => 'index')); 
            }
            else
            {
                //why is it getting to this point with correct details?
                debug('failed'); exit;
            }
    }
}
```

Not sure if I'm missing something that would mean that the `$this->auth->login()` would fail?
I did try renaming it all User instead of Admin to see if it was that causing he issues, however the outcome was still the same. The admins are being added through cake using the authcomponent to hash the password like so:

```
class Admin extends AppModel {

    public function beforeSave($options = array())
    {
        if(isset($this->data['Admin']['password'])) {
            $this->data['Admin']['password'] = AuthComponent::password($this->data['Admin']['password']);
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just incase anyone was having the same issue, I found what was causing the problem and it was just a silly mistake.

I had set the Auth component in the AppController, and then again in the AdminsController as you can see from the code above. This was causing the issue, as it is only needed in the AppController.

Answer (score 3):

By default Auth uses the User model of authentication. Based on your output of `debug($this->request)` it seems you are using a model named "Admin". So specify that using `userModel` key in Auth component settings. Check the manual for specifics.

Comment: Did not know it took User model by default, however have added the userModel key to the auth component and still having no luck. Auth Components now looks like: 
`public $components = array( 'Auth' => array( 'loginRedirect' => array('controller' => 'admins', 'action' => 'index'), 'logoutRedirect' => array('controller' => 'admins', 'action' => 'index'), 'authenticate' => array( 'Form' => array( 'userModel' => 'Admin', ) ) ) );`

Comment: Check the query log, does Auth query the db with the credentials you posted?

Comment: ok, how would I go about checking the query log? its not something ive used before.

Comment: Well attempted to check query log using:

`$log = $this->Model->getDataSource()->getLog(false, false);
debug($log);`


and got the following result:

'array(
 'log' => array(),
 'count' => (int) 0,
 'time' => null
)'`

but im not sure if this is correct

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered similar problems in the past and I find that passing through the `$this->request->data` property into the `AuthComponent::login()` method directly sometimes works. Like this:

```
$this->Auth->login($this->request->data)
```

The only issue with this is that only the information you pass through will be put into the session. So in your case, you'd only be able to access the username and password from the session.

I'm sure there's a reason as to why this isn't working as you expect though.

Comment: Don't do that. Passing an array to AuthComponent::login() will directly add that info to session and log you in without even querying db.

Answer (score 0):

You did not specify what version of CakePhp you were using. I needed to change the `allow` parameter when I upgraded from 2.0 to 2.3 - reference in the [CakePhp Cookbook / ACL](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/simple-acl-controlled-application/simple-acl-controlled-application.html)

```
public function beforeFilter() {
    parent::beforeFilter();

    // For CakePHP 2.0
    $this->Auth->allow('*');

    // For CakePHP 2.1 and up
    $this->Auth->allow();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to define Auth in admin controller. Insted you can Use same login.ctp file to login for user and admin (make it using swith case), in Admincontroller for security use this code in beforerender

```
if($this->Session->read('Auth.User.role') != 'admin')
{
 $this->Session->setFlash('Hack Attempt detecetd via.'$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
$this->redirect('/logout');
}
```

And in usermodel,in before-save replace Admin with User